# Send sessions to subdomain with ajax?

Tags: ajax, session, cross-domain, subdomain, session-cookies

I want to create mobile version of my website and do all process with just sending request to main website and get result then design for mobile.But I need do this for each user differently thats why I need user id access on sub domain or all domains releted with ex.com 
I searched about it and I found this

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  '.$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
$some_name  = session_name("some_name");
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example.com');
session_start();
echo('id=',$_SESSION['user']['id']);
```

it works with different opened tabs.For example one tab show www.ex.com another show m.ex.com sessions is same(if session id is 12 on www.ex.com it means on m.ex.com session id is 12) but when I send request with ajax(jquery) it doesnt work it echo this:`'id='`

Comment: try `$echo = $_SESSION['user']['id']; echo 'id=$echo';` or i think just `echo 'id='.$_SESSION['user']['id'];` parenthesis not needed.

Comment: i didnt understand what you were saying the first time - i thought it was throwing an error on the echo line - is there more code? the request? its not echoing an id probably because it isnt getting set correctly

Comment: where are you setting `$_SESSION['user']['id']`?

Comment: I just want to send sessions to my subdomain to use it sessions to catch user session id for example like a facebook

Comment: i found docs for using .example.com...not sure if this is what you have been looking at. `$currentCookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); 

$rootDomain = '.example.com'; 

session_set_cookie_params( 
    0, 
    $currentCookieParams["path"], 
    $rootDomain, 
    $currentCookieParams["secure"], 
    $currentCookieParams["httponly"] 
); 

session_name('some_name'); 
session_start(); 

setcookie($cookieName, $cookieValue, time() + 3600, '/', $rootDomain);` http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php - its the 4th example.

Comment: I have done this and showed on question itself

Comment: i dont understand "showed on question itself"